# Restoring .Java file association

Tags: windows-7, java

Today I updated intellij 14 and by mistake told it to associate with .java

I've since been unable to restore the .java file association after a number of attempts based on information found from Google. I've edited the registry, used a program known as "DefaultProgramsEditor" (which seems likely a lovely program and am sorry it didn't work) and tried setting it through cmd to no avail:

[image]

In the end I tried deleting the reg entry just to get a "fresh start" as I think I should be able to restore it by reinstalling java, but this hasn't worked either.

I'm unable to do a system restore, and don't know what else to do - I do know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows) question should work, except I've been unable to find a way to apply it correctly.

Primarily I would be happy if someone knew which Java installer (JDK or otherwise) I could run that would restore the file association.

Comment: The question you linked to is regarding `.jar` files not `.java` files. They don't generally have the same association ...

Answer (score 0):

This page gives instructions on changing file associations in Windows 7 and Windows 8:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5702362_change-file-associations-windows-7.html

You may also be able to right-click on the file and select Open with > Choose default program.... (This works for me on Windows 8; I see your question is tagged as Windows 7 and I don't have a Windows 7 machine to test on.)

Comment: I have tried this - the issue lies with Java requiring a more complex path than just the file, which can't be set from those windows. See the question I linked to